# Django and Python

Tags: python, html, css, django, scripting

I am trying to create a Django website that will have several pages. On each of these pages I am looking to create a Python task.

One of these tasks on one of the pages might be for a user to enter an input such as a name John Smith and click search. I wish for the Python script to then go and search for all John Smith related material on the internet and return results.

Firstly, would the Python script be able to sit on the Django web page to do this? Or am I misunderstanding what Django can do?

Secondly, will I just mix the script in with the HTML etc?

Comment: Hi, the python script won't be able to sit in the web page, the html template is going to send a request to the backend of django and in this backend you will have to use some kind of web scrap library to go to google and return the results

Comment: So the function would sit in the server itself ?

Comment: Yep, you can't do this in frontend (html template)

Comment: What you are talking about is having an HTML form that makes a request (POST) to the server to go perform the search and return the results. You can either use a normal form for this or you can look to implement it using AJAX which may be useful since it sounds like you want to then go scrape websites for content which will take a while. You could also use websockets and promises for long-polling  if required

Comment: Can you link me to any YouTube videos  /channels / websites of how to do this please ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.